# How do I select a RowKey range with Azure Table Storage?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I would like to query my azure tablestorage using PrimaryKey plus I would like to check my RowKey is within a range. For example the range 02001 to 02999

Can someone tell me how I can do this? I understand how to query the PK with a simple:

```
where fooEntiy.PartitionKey == partition
```

but I don't know how I can query fooEntity.RowKey.

Also if I do this by specifying a range then will it still retrieve all the entries for that partition and then check to see if they match the range?

Thank you for your advice,

Mariko

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your query could look something like this:

```
where fooEntity.PartitionKey == partionKey
    && fooEntity.RowKey.CompareTo(lowerBoundRowKey) >= 0
    && fooEntity.RowKey.CompareTo(upperBoundRowKey) <= 0
```

This should return all of the items between the `lowerBoundRowKey` and the `upperBoundRowKey` including those values (if you don't want it to be inclusive, just use > and < rather than >= and <=).

You will not need to do any other filtering than this.

It looks like you're already padding your numbers that you're storing in the RowKey with leading zeros which is a good thing as this range will be a lexical range, not a numeric range.

e.g. running this query with `lowerBoundKey = 10` and `upperBoundKey = 100` will not return an item with a RowKey of 20.

If you pad it with zeros however `lowerBoundKey = 00010` and `upperBoundKey = 00100` will return an item with a RowKey of 00020.

Comment: +1 - and one more point on this - if you run the query make sure you check for continuation tokens - even if less than a 1000 rows are returned you can still get a continuation token.

Comment: Good point.  Or you can use .AsTableServiceQuery(). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee741713.aspx  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee758648.aspx

Comment: If I need to query 1000 / 100k available records and all records have same partition key. What is the better between 100 point query and sing range query?

Comment: If you just want everything in the same partition key, just exclude the part of the query that relates to the RowKey.  Or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 2):

This will bring entities using the specified range of RowKey values with specified PartitionKey:

" PartitionKey eq 'your partitonKey value' and (RowKey gt '02001' and RowKey lt '02999') "

Find more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd894031.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd135725.aspx).
Hope this helps.