# Azure table query failing with bad request error

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

I am querying my azure table storage for some output. I can do it in Azure Storage Explorer, and to me the query generated in my code LOOKS like it should work as it does in Azure Storage Explorer. It fails and returns bad request, and I just don't see what is wrong with it.

The code that generates the query:

```
public QueryOutputResult GetOutputFromQueryResult(EquityDataEntity queryRecord, int outputPeriod)
{
    var resultDates = Helpers.GetValidOutputDates(queryRecord.RowKey, outputPeriod);
    var partitionFilter =  TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, queryRecord.PartitionKey);
    var startDateFilter =
        TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate("RowKey", QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual, resultDates[0].Date);
    var endDateFilter =
        TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate("TradeDate", QueryComparisons.LessThanOrEqual, resultDates[^1].Date);

    var filter = TableQuery.CombineFilters(
        TableQuery.CombineFilters(
            partitionFilter,
            TableOperators.And,
            startDateFilter),
        TableOperators.And, endDateFilter);

    var query = new TableQuery<EquityDataEntity>().Where(filter);
    var results = HistoricalDataTable.ExecuteQuery(query).ToList();

    return OutputHelpers.CreateOutputResultsFromQueryTriggers(queryRecord, results);

}
```

produces this:

> ((PartitionKey eq 'SPY') and (RowKey ge datetime'2022-01-24T05:00:00.0000000Z')) and (RowKey le datetime'2022-01-27T05:00:00.0000000Z')

Here is it working in ASE:

[image: Storage Explorer View]

The error message doesn't help much (at least it doesn't help me)

> ```
>   Message "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."   string
> ```

Comment: @Guarav Mantri...any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just using the `Date` portion of the `DateTime` fields (resultDates[0].Date and resultDates[1].Date). The library is most likely having trouble with the time portion of the request.

Comment: There is also this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/5933042/89184

Comment: I am already using .Date....QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual, resultDates[0].Date